# C++ | Mostrar determinante de una matriz 3x3

Tags: c++, matrices

Quisiera saber cómo hago para copiar las dos primeras filas de mi matriz y convertirlas en las líneas 3 y 4 en este caso para poder hacer Sarrus y no tener que sacar determinante por cofactores.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {

    int matriz[3][3];
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i <= 2; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= 2; j++) {
            cout << "Digite un numero [" << i << "][" << j << "]: ";
            cin >> matriz[i][j];
        }
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Bienvenido. ¿Qué interesante?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Creo que no deberías copiar las filas.
Es un gasto de memoria y complicará tu código de manera innecesaria.
El cálculo de un determinante de una matriz 3x3 es conocido y sencillo de programar:

```
int det{0};
for(int i=0;i<3;i++)
   det += matriz[0][i]*matriz[1][(i+1)%3]*matriz[2][(i+2)%3] -
          matriz[2][i]*matriz[1][(i+1)%3]*matriz[0][(i+2)%3];
```

Esta forma de expresar los cálculos puede no ser la óptima pero es la que reproduce los cálculos que haría un humano al aplicar la regla de Sarrus.

Comment: Buena respuesta, también pensé en eso. De hecho tengo la respuesta lista para cuando tobias muestre lo que hizo. Se agradece tu aporte pero evita responder hasta que la pregunta esté bien.